# Firebase hosting using emulator not rewriting to destination

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

*Note the issue I'm having is with the firebase emulator*

It appears that I am unable to rewrite a request where the requested URI is `/baz`  to a JSON file called **baz.json**. I would expect that I should be able to rewrite such that the JSON content in the path to **baz.json** would be provided in the response.

I have the following example in my firebase.json:

```json
{
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "host": "0.0.0.0",
      "port": 8888
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "foo/bar",
    "ignore": [],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/baz",
        "destination": "<path to baz.json here>",
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For `<path to baz.json here>` I have tried the following:

- absolute path
- relative path

The result I get when running `firebase emulators:start` for both of the above is:

```
$ curl localhost:8888/baz       
                   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /baz</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I would expect to get the contents of the file **baz.json** (which is some arbitrary JSON; let's say {} for now).